# package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found, searching: ['/opt/ros/foxy']

Tags: ros, ros2, gazebo-simu

I completed the [Quick Start Guide](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/) for **Foxy**. All went well.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on **WSL2** Windows 11.

```bash
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

```bash
$ printenv ROS_DISTRO
foxy
```

```bash
$ gazebo -version
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org


Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org
```

However, when try to run the [simulation](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#gazebo-simulation)

```bash
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
$ ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo empty_world.launch.py
```

It failed with the message

```
Package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found: "package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found, searching: ['/opt/ros/foxy']"
```

How to fix it? I found a similar thread on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/rwh9e9/please_help_gazebo_error_package_not_found/) but it didn't help much.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-turtlebot3-gazebo @Bilal

Comment: `sudo apt-install ros-$ROS_DISTRO-turtlebot3-gazebo` where is the `$ROS_DISTRO` in your case is `foxy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @Bilal in the comment, I solved the issue by running

```bash
sudo apt-install ros-foxy-turtlebot3-gazebo
```

Then, run the simulation:

```bash
set env export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
run ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py
```

Result:
[image: Gazezo WSL sceenshot]